# Proving Limits by the Definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that: $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^3 = 0$$

I have that:
For all $\epsilon>0\ \exists\ \delta\ = \epsilon^3$ such that for all $x, |x|<\delta.$ 
Then $|x^3| = |x||x||x|\le\delta\ \le\ \epsilon^3$.

Is the epsilon chosen correct? or should $\delta$ be $\le \tfrac\epsilon3$?

Comment: Where you have $|x^3|\leq\delta$, it should be $|x^3|<\delta^3$.

Comment: If $|x|\leq \delta$ then $|x^3|\leq \delta^3=\epsilon^9$, so that's not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Choose $\delta=\epsilon^{1/3}$, then $|x|\lt \delta\implies |x^3|=|x|^3\lt\delta^3=\epsilon$